# JavaFX & CSS 'Unexpected function' in gradients

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2

I used a button generator online and copied the css from it to my javafx css. I selected everything and used "Convert to W3C CSS" Something like that... Now, I get the following errors:

```
"com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain 
com.package.project.Main
May 30, 2017 6:43:23 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing 

style.css: Unexpected function '-webkit-linear-gradient(' while parsing 
'background-image' at [27,22]
May 30, 2017 6:43:23 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing style.css: Unexpected function '-moz-linear-
gradient(' while parsing 'background-image' at [28,22]
May 30, 2017 6:43:23 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing style.css: Unexpected function '-ms-linear-
gradient(' while parsing 'background-image' at [29,22]
May 30, 2017 6:43:23 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing style.css: Unexpected function '-o-linear-
gradient(' while parsing 'background-image' at [30,22]
May 30, 2017 6:43:23 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing style.css: expected series of <size> while 
parsing 'text-shadow' at [35,17]
May 30, 2017 6:43:23 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing style.css: Unexpected function '-webkit-linear-
gradient(' while parsing 'background-image' at [46,22]
May 30, 2017 6:43:23 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing style.css: Unexpected function '-moz-linear-
gradient(' while parsing 'background-image' at [47,22]
May 30, 2017 6:43:23 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing style.css: Unexpected function '-ms-linear-
gradient(' while parsing 'background-image' at [48,22]
May 30, 2017 6:43:23 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing style.css: Unexpected function '-o-linear-
gradient(' while parsing 'background-image' at [49,22]
```

Using the following stylesheet:

```
.btn {
    background: #e60c0c;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e60c0c, #750f0f);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e60c0c, #750f0f);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e60c0c, #750f0f);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e60c0c, #750f0f);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e60c0c, #750f0f);
    -webkit-border-radius: 16;
    -moz-border-radius: 16;
    border-radius: 16px;
    text-shadow: 4px 3px 2px #666666;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #b5abff;
    font-size: 27px;
    padding: 34px 34px 34px 34px;
    border: solid #253138 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #750f0f;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #750f0f, #e60c0c);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #750f0f, #e60c0c);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #750f0f, #e60c0c);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #750f0f, #e60c0c);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #750f0f, #e60c0c);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Can anybody tell my why I'm receiving theses errors ? Thanks all

Comment: That looks like CSS that targets HTML. None of those properties or values are valid for CSS targeting JavaFX. See the [JavaFX CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for valid properties and values.

Comment: What makes it target html ? Do I just have to add `-fx-` ? Because text-shadow and color don't have the -fx- version.... For -webkit-linear-gradient  it gives a warning that it looks for a `<uri>`...

Comment: I guess I should say that the problem is that it *doesn't* target JavaFX. Nothing in JavaFX (at least by default) has CSS properties called `background`, `background-image`, etc, and `-webkit-linear-gradient(...)` is not a known function. The CSS has to use properties and values that make sense in the context in which it is applied. (I'm not a CSS expert, so I can't make this precise, but the way I think of it is that JavaFX uses the CSS *language*, i.e. syntax. HTML uses it too, but with a different set of properties. Sort of analogous to XML files with different schemas.)

Comment: Alright I'll try just to copy the code using javafx syntax.... Thanks

Comment: Using JavaFX *properties*. You are already using the correct  CSS *syntax* :)

Comment: That's what I meant :p